# Set date format in HTML form input to YYYY only

Tags: html, date, forms, html-input

I currently have an HTML form with a `date` input field.  Is it possible to set this to the format `YYYY` only?  I am not interested in the days or months and need the year in this format for some PHP processing.

I know I could do some extra work to get the date into the `YYYY` format afterwards, but I was wondering if there was a way to force the user to supply it in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this might work:

`<input id="startdate" name="startdate" min="1900" max="2100" type="date">`

Comment: Otherwise you could just make the input validate an integer and specify the min and max

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work, I think, provided that I don't give it `type="date"` as some browsers override the settings.  Just need to do some validation for if user enters year outside `min` and `max` and perhaps set current year with some JavaScript so it doesn't crash in the future.

Comment: Cool, you could also do the validation to only enter the year with javascript, you can also change the control to a slider or do all your validation and error handling using php